# Firefox записывает на диск очень много данных

Tags: linux, selenium, firefox

Я на виртуальном сервере (vps) с Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (ENG) запускаю firefox с помощью selenium. Я обнаружил, что при этом при переходе по разным страницам у меня на диск записывается очень много данных. Статистика сервера говорит например, что входящий трафик за 3 часа был 3.5ГБ, а на жесткий диск при этом было записано 44ГБ. При этом моя программа на selenium ничего не сохраняет на сервер, она собирает информацию со  страниц и далее отправляет её в базу данных mysql на другой сервер. Погуглив, я нашёл [статью](https://lubuntu.ru/viewtopic.php?t=3971), где в одном из комментарием приводится интересная информация:

> Дальше не совсем по теме.
>   Логи - мелочь, по сравнению с Firefox, который грузит диск больше чем что либо другое. Немного не по теме прочитал в инете https://geektimes.ru/post/280792/ .
>   «.... на твердотельный накопитель SSD загружаются большие объемы данных вплоть до 10 ГБ. Если в браузере постоянно открыто множество окон с «тяжелыми» сайтами, то можно ожидать еще большего количества записанных Firefox данных. Главным виновником случившегося оказался браузер Firefox. Он загружал от 300 КБ до 2 МБ ежесекундно. Запись велась в файл с названием recovery.js. Как оказалось, это резервная копия сессии Firefox. Она используется в том случае, если «падает» браузер или операционная система. Это полезная, но ресурсоемкая функция. И если учесть то, что у SSD ограниченный ресурс, то здесь уже нужно решить для себя, что полезнее — рабочий диск или же восстановление текущей сессии браузера после его падения. .....
>
> Проблема решается настройкой в `about:config`
>
> ```
> browser.sessionstore.interval 15000
> ```

Вопрос в следующем: где в linux (если нет графического интерфейса) находится файл с настройками конфигурации firefox, в котором как мне кажется и можно изменить значение `browser.sessionstore.interval`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем помог коллега. Как оказалось, webdriver при запуске создаёт новый профиль для firefox, независимо от того, есть он или нет. Ему также можно передать профиль как параметр. Для этого можно скопировать папку профиля firefox, которую создал webdriver и которую поместил в /tmp (в моём случае она называется например так `rust_mozprofile.mIg1OpBGYQSP`), скопировать её в нужное место, найти в ней файл настроек `prefs.js`, отредактировать его нужным образом и указать эту папку с профилем при создании webdriver.
Пример кода ниже:

```
ffprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("/home/firefox-profile")
firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
firefox_options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=ffprofile, executable_path='/home/drivers/geckodriver', options=firefox_options)
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
```

В коде выше `"/home/firefox-profile"` это скопированная папка с профилем и отредактированным в ней файлом `prefs.js`

Answer (score 0):

Настройки находятся в файле [`prefs.js`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Prefs.js_file) в каталоге [профиля](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder). т.е. по умолчанию где-то в:

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile>/prefs.js
```

Comment: У меня в директории `~/.mozilla/firefox/` только 2 папки: 'Crash Reports' и 'Pending Pings'.
Глобальный поиск файла `prefs.js` дал 4 результата, но все они лежат в папке tmp. То есть как я понял создаются при каждой новой сессии.

Comment: @Alex, значит `selenium` использует свои пути к профилям и создаёт из динамически... тут  нужно копать в сторону его настроек... с этим я ещё помочь не смогу...